# JavaScript make custom object from another file for testing

Tags: javascript, qunit

I'm writing Qunit tests for the following html file:

```
var PinPointService = {
     doAjax: function(doAjax_params) {
          //do some stuff
     }
     //a bunch more variables and functions
}
```

The test I'm writing in a seperate file:

```
QUnit.test("test", function(assert) {
    var array = [];
    PinPointService.doAjax(array);
    //assert some stuff
});
```

The error I get:

```
PinPointService is not defined
```

My main js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Pinpoint Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\path\to\jshamcrest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\path\to\core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\path\to\integration.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\path\to\jsmockito-1.0.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
  <script src="C:\path\to\pinpoint.html"></script>
  <script src="C:\path\to\pinpointTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there something additional I have to do besides including pinpoint.html in my main js file? I'm new to JavaScript, so I think I could be missing some fundamentals of how the language works in contrast to Java which I'm very comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import the file where

```
QUnit.test("test", function(assert) {
    var array = [];
    PinPointService.doAjax(array);
    //assert some stuff
});
```

is located, after you imported PinPointService.

So in your html file it should be something like

```
...
 <script src="C:\path\to\pinpointTest.js"></script>
<script src="file_containing_the_code_above"></script>
...
```

the html page is read and included from top to bottom so if you have not included the pinpointTest file yet, you can not use anything inside it.

Comment: Sorry if my original post wasn't clear.
  <script src="C:\path\to\pinpoint.html"></script>
is where 
var PinPointService = {
     doAjax: function(doAjax_params) {
          //do some stuff
     }
     //a bunch more variables and functions
}
is located

sorry about this formatting, I don't know how to fix it. I've already included that file before my test file, but it still isn't defined for some reason.

Comment: wait but that is not supposed to be a .html file. if you are importing as a script it should be a .js file

Comment: Okay, I see. It's one big super file (I didn't make it) It contains both html and JavaScript in it so it's ultimately an html file if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: it is but you can not use the script syntax you are using to import it. If I were you I would separate the javascript from the html so you can import it wherever.

Comment: Ok that explains a lot! I don't know why it's one super file containing html and javascript, that doesn't sound like it's in good practice.